# How do I pass data from an AJAX PHP result to a seperate PHP function through AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When selecting an option belonging to one PHP file, my goal is to pass this option's current row ID to a seperate PHP file so that I can use it there.

This is from the file I'm trying to fetch:

```
echo '<div id="folderContentTableContainer">';
echo '<table class="table table-searchable-asc">';
if (count($contents) > 0) {
// Start of table
foreach ($contents as $content) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $content['title'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $content['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a id="cloneContent" class="fa fa-clone"></a></td>';
    echo '<td><a id="removeContent" class="fa fa-trash"></a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
} else {
// return nothing
```

Now I'll want to use $content['id'] in a seperate PHP file to query the database.

I'm currently fetching the file content like this:

```
$('#content').on('click', '#folderContainerUl li', function () {
    var id = event.target.id;
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo ROOTDIR; ?>pages/ajax/getPasswordsFolderContent.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: ({
            uuid: '<?php echo $_GET['uuid']; ?>',
            folder: id
        }),
        success: function (content) {
            $('#folders-content-container').html(content);

        }
    })
});
```

The file content will then be placed into the data from getPasswordsFolders.php, which includes this:

```
echo '<div id="folderUlContainer">';
echo '<ul id="folderContainerUl">';
foreach ($folders as $folder) {
$children = $mfdb->select('password_folders', '*', array('AND' => array('parent_id' => $folder['id']), 'ORDER' => 'title ASC'));
if (count($children) > 0) {
    echo '<li id="' . $folder['id'] . '">' . $folder['title'] . '</li>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        echo '<li id="' . $folder['id'] . '">' . $child['title'] . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</li>';
} else {
    echo '<li id="' . $folder['id'] . '">' . $folder['title'] . '</li>';
}
}
echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Firstly, you're duplicating `id` attributes in your HTML which is invalid. They need to be unique. You can use classes if you want to group elements together. Secondly, the selector you're using, `#folderContainerUl li`, seems to have no relation to the HTML you're generating in the PHP example...?

Comment: You can do anything you want in your ajax php function, so you could either just write a php function and call it from there, or you can just add it into your ajax php function

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've included the #folderContainerUl snippet at the bottem of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, as [Rory McMcrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan) said, you are duplicating the IDs, try to use classes instead.

then you can send an ajax request as following:

```
$('.cloneContent').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().prev().text();

    $.ajax({
        url:'your-url?id='+id,
        method:'get',
        ...
    });

    //OR

    $.ajax({
        url:'your-url',
        method:'post',
        data:{id:id},
        ...
    });
});
```

EDIT:

to simplify your work you can pass the id as an attribute of the anchor `a` as:

```
echo '<td><a class="fa fa-clone cloneContent" data="'.$content['id'].'"></a></td>';
```

so now you can get the id by:

```
var id = $(this).attr('data');
```

instead of: `var id = $(this).parent().prev().text();`

Comment: In my case I had to use `$('#content').on('click', '.cloneContent', function () {` for the function instead, not sure why really. Otherwise it worked perfect.

Comment: @Wessah yeah, if your HTML elements will be added to the document in the future, you need to attach the click listener this way or by using [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)